# AWS Javascript SDK v3 - Typescript doesn't compile due to error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to build my project that uses the AWS Javascript SDK v3. Here my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "coverage",
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

And here an example of the build error I get (I've strip out some of the output for brevity sake):

```
node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/types/models/models_1.d.ts:727:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.

node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/types/models/models_1.d.ts:727:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blob'.

node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb/types/models.d.ts:19:86 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'File'.
```

I don't understand why this is giving me such an issue, even if I have installed the `@types/node` module to support node typing

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Turned out that in order for typescript to find the `Blob`, `File` etc. names I had to add the `dom` entry to the lib in my tsconfig.json. Here my final tsconfig, which allow me to build the project correctly

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "coverage",
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. However, my app runs on Nodejs. Will there be any issues adding `dom` to this project—which presumably checks for browser compatibility? Strange that `AWS` couldn't compile against vanilla Nodejs?

Comment: It'll throw more type conflicts and errors if we add 'dom' in our node app. Does anyone know other solution?

Comment: @user2734550 checkout walter-barbagallo solution below

Answer (score 18):

Without including the `dom` lib in the `tsconfig.json`

```
// src/@types/dom.ts (or any file included in the tsc compilation)

export {}

declare global {
  type ReadableStream = unknown
  type Blob = unknown
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Why didn't AWS do something like this is beyond me...

Answer (score 2):

It is always recommended to use the `aws-sdk` v3 in combination with Node 18. If you do not want to include `DOM`, you can specify Node 18 in the tsconfig.

```json
{
    //...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target":"ES2022",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2022"],
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Additionally, you should use `@types/node` in version 18:

```
npm i -D @types/node@18
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `declare global` solution but I had to declare one of the types as 'any' to get around a class that implemented the Storage class:

```
export declare class UniversalStorage implements Storage {
```

therefore instead of unknown, I just made all the offenders type 'any'